# java netbean inserting data to db does not work

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans, insert

I'm trying to insert data to data base by my own interface using java netbean
But I'm stuck with insert query doesn't work here is my code segment

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

    package youthsociety;

    import java.beans.Statement;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;

    /**
     *
     * @author Rathnayaka RMBS
     */
    public class dbop {
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youthsociety";
        String username="root";
        String password="";
        Connection con=null;
        Statement st=null;


        public void addmember(memberdata m){
            try{
                con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                String query="INSERT INTO members VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                st=(Statement)con.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(query);

            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

    }
```

st.executeUpdate(query) mark as wrong.

Comment: *insert query doesn't work here* what doesn't work ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide the *complete error message* and/or *stack strace* you get.

Comment: Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: You're passing `memberdata m` but where you're setting it as `VALUES` to the insert statement? And do not ignore Exceptions just use `e.printStackTrace()` inside `catch` block to get exact reason for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me explain your problem.

1. You don’t have configured jdbc driver.
2. Don’t need to cast anything!
3. You have question mark ‘?’ In your query, and you are using simple Statement class to execute instead of PreparedStatement.

Now, if you are using simple Statement, follow this link:
[A Java MySQL INSERT example (using Statement)](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-statement)

If you are using PreparedStatement, you can follow this link:
[A Java MySQL INSERT example (using PreparedStatement)](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 0):

here you have to use this After the query

then you need to give some value in (?)

you can also do like this

```
try{
            con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            String query="INSERT INTO members VALUES(?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query)
            pst.setInt(1,anyInt);
            pst.setString(2,anyString);
            pst.setString(3,anyString);

            int rowcount = pst.executeUpdate();

            if(rowcount>0){
             System.out.println("Done");
            }
            else{
             System.out.println("Faild");
            }
              
            

        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace()
        }
```